# Springer author-date bibliography in Lyx

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, lyx, harvard-style

How can one set-up LyX to succesfully compile *at least* the provided Springer example?

How to reproduce:
New from template -> `springer/svjour3.lyx`

Delete the two missing images in the figures or just delete the figures.

Compile successfully.

Output:

[image]

Bibtex bibliography:
[image]

Comment: Basically **any** author-year style would be good but I wasn't able to make work any yet. I can then somehow hack the right one to work in the final LateX.

Comment: What is your LaTeX installation and which LyX version? The template works well for me without any modifications if I just compile out-of-the-box on Ubuntu with LyX 2.2.0 and TeX Live 2016.

Comment: I think OpenSUSE 13.2 Lyx 2.1.?, I  just left that computer. But reproduced now with OpenSUSE 12.3, Lyx 2.1.4, TeXLive 2012, but this is an older computer with newer LyX than was default here.

Comment: Unfortunately we often face the choice of supporting an older TeX Live version or a newer one. We try our best to support as many versions as possible, but when we can only support one, we choose the newest. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

This is strange. One must select natbib and author-year style which I tried many times before, but also one must delete the non-bibtex bibliography entries, otherwise it just crashes with:

> ! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year
>   citations.

Comment: I am not sure if this is useful to others or if I should delete the question.